# Maximal ideals of the ring of all continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be the ring of all continuous functions from the interval $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$. For each $a\in[0,1]$ let
$$A_a=\{f\in R \mid f(a)=0\}$$

Now firstly, this is part of an assignment problem, please give me hints/insight into the problem, and not a solution.

I want to show that $A_a$ is a maximal ideal - but I am not sure how to think of my set. I have dealt with polynomial rings, perhaps some analogy?

Now, how to know this is a subring? Well if $f_1(a)=0$ and $f_2(a)=0$ clearly this is closed under subtraction and multiplication. Showing it is maximal is harder and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: use \mid for $\mid$

Comment: Moreover using compactness of $[0,1]$,these are the **only** maximal ideals of given ring.

Comment: @ContinuityOfFailure There are several duplicates, both of the flavor using the domain [0,1] and all of the reals.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to see that $A_a$ is an *ideal*. That's stronger than being a subring. Anyway...

> but I am not sure how to think of my set.

Hint: it's a kernel.

Comment: And if you require your subrings to have their own multiplicative identity (let alone requiring them to have the original ring's identity) then $A_a$ is in fact not a subring.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the application
$$\phi_a:R\to\Bbb R$$
defined by $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$.

Is $\phi_a$ a morphism? Is it surjective? What is its kernel? Remember that given a ring $S$ and an ideal $\mathfrak m$, then $\mathfrak m$ is maximal if and only if the quotient ring $S/\mathfrak m$ is a field.

Comment: Secondary dumb question: In terms of polynomials I can see exactly what a quotient ring is when taking an ideal. But here I cannot. What does it mean to mod out a set of functions?

Comment: @ContinuityOfFailure It means you identify any two functions as being "the same" (in your quotient) if they evaluate on $a$ to the same value. Of course, this partitions all of the functions according to what value they take on $a$, and these values are the elements of $\Bbb R$...

Comment: @Anon So in $\frac{\Bbb c([0,1],\Bbb R)}{A_a}$ if we have $f_1(a)=f_2(a)$ then $f_1=f_2$?

Comment: Yes, since $(f_1-f_2)(a)=0$ means $f_1-f_2\in A_a\implies f_1\equiv f_2$ in the quotient.

Comment: @Anon Oh I didn't see this before opening that new question sorry!(you didn't tag me)